# Irreducible polynomial in Dedekind domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

In a PID, we know that if we know that the coefficients of an irreducible polynomial don't have any common factor. Is the same true in a Dedekind domain ?

$\bf{Updated: }$

or Are there irreducible polynomials of the form $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0$ over a Dedekind domain $R$ such that $a_i \in \mathcal{P}$ for all $i$?

Note: There are such linear polynomials. See comments.

Comment: Just after posting the question, I observed that for linear polynomials it's not true. For example, consider $ ax+b$ where $a, b$ are distinct elements of a fix prime ideal.

Comment: Sorry! my bad. There was a typo in the question. Updated it now.

Comment: How about $2x^2 + (1+\sqrt{-5})x + 2$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$?